# Does anyone have the electrical wiring diagram for the instrument cluster for a 1999 Audi A4 B5?

Tags: electrical, audi, connector, instrument-cluster, wiring-diagram

I'm in the process of repair and upgrade of the instrument cluster for my Audi A4 B5 car. I was able to find a few manuals online that show the pin outs for the Green & Blue connectors for my model cluster. But I could not find any info about the outside temperature/gear selector display pin outs.

I would be highly grateful if anyone here has any info to share about the details of the 10 pin connector pin out and also the wiring diagram for the cluster. Attached below if the VDO code of the cluster and also the temperature display.

[image: Cluster VDO code]
[image: Outside temp display serial no and connector]

Comment: quattro Sedan or wagon, or just a sedan?

Comment: turbo or non turbo?

Comment: Take it apart and follow the traces?